# Form: password with images?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to implement a password field in a PHP form, where the password would be a sequence of digits but rather than typing them on the keyboard, the user would have to select the proper images (from 0 to 9, like some online bank accounts do).
How would I be able to do that?
Thanks!

I guess I would have to monitor each onClick on images and then modify a variable accordingly, but I'm not sure how to do that, I can work with PHP but my javascript skills are low:)

So my logic would be. When onClick on an image, it triggers a function image() that will set the variable "password" to the value of the image concatenated with the former value of "password". So my questions: how will this function work with several images? and how do I concatenate so that when clicking for example on image1 then image3 then image2, "password" will get the value: "132".
Thanks!

```js
function image() {
  var password = document.getElementById("image").value;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="image1.png" value="1" onClick="image();">
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, please include what you've tried so far and describe where you're stuck at so that people can help you.

Comment: _“like most online bank accounts do”_ - do they …? Mine doesn’t. So please give a proper example of what you want this to look like, resp. how exactly the user is supposed to interact with it.

Comment: Start by working your way through an introductory JavaScript tutorial. Stackoverflow isn't here to build software for you because you don't know the programming language or have any idea of how to write your application.

Comment: I added some clarifications. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a working snippet, I added all the images manually - you can do that "better" with a loop in PHP:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) { ?>
<img id="password-digit-<?php echo $i; ?>" src="password-digit-<?php echo $i; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $i; ?>" data-digit="<?php echo $i; ?>">
<php } ?>
```

If you want the password input invisible, use `hidden` attribute on it, like:

```
<input type="password" hidden>
```

And, to send it via HTML form to some PHP endpoint, add the `name` attribute.

```
<input type="password" name="password">
```

```js
const images   = document.querySelectorAll('img[id^="password-digit"]')
const password = document.getElementById('password');

images.forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener('click', () => {
    password.value = password.value + img.dataset.digit;
    console.log('Current password:', password.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<img id="password-digit-0" src="password-digit-0.png" alt="0" data-digit="0">
<img id="password-digit-1" src="password-digit-1.png" alt="1" data-digit="1">
<img id="password-digit-2" src="password-digit-2.png" alt="2" data-digit="2">
<img id="password-digit-3" src="password-digit-3.png" alt="3" data-digit="3">
<img id="password-digit-4" src="password-digit-4.png" alt="4" data-digit="4">
<img id="password-digit-5" src="password-digit-5.png" alt="5" data-digit="5">
<img id="password-digit-6" src="password-digit-6.png" alt="6" data-digit="6">
<img id="password-digit-7" src="password-digit-7.png" alt="7" data-digit="7">
<img id="password-digit-8" src="password-digit-8.png" alt="8" data-digit="8">
<img id="password-digit-9" src="password-digit-9.png" alt="9" data-digit="9">

<hr>

<input id="password" type="password" value="">
```

Comment: What if I want to change the CSS for an image, once clicked? I would like to change the color of the background. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Image elements can't have a value attribute. I used a data attribute in the code below to store the needed value. Also i replaced your inline click handler with a Javascript one. It is easier to maintain and easy use of `this` to get the clicked element.

I added the clicked number to the input value with the `+=` operator.

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("image")).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', image);
});

function image() {
  document.getElementById('password').value += this.getAttribute('data-number');
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="image1.png" data-number="1">
<img class="image" src="image2.png" data-number="2">
<img class="image" src="image3.png" data-number="3">

<input id="password">
```

Comment: It seems to work great as well, thanks! (so I'm not sure what's the best option between this one and the one above :)

Comment: There is not much difference, use what is clearest for you/fits your code style the best.